# Managed package field is not available to extract or SOQL query

Tags: managed-package, data-export, workbench

I have this custom field (Other Source 3) that I want to data extract out as below :

[image: Managed Package custom field]

It is a Managed Package custom field available on Salesforce environment that is **Not editable** and of type Lookup(user) & visible to ALL profiles in the field level security.

It is able to be added to page layout and doesn't seem like a deleted field as below :

[image: Other Source 3]

Yet, when I go into [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php) or Dataloader and try to query out the field, **it isn't there**?

[image]

How do I extract out the data from that field??

Comment: did you figure out why it wasn't showing up? Was it any access issue or due to other reason? Also can you do describe on the sobject and see if that field show up?

Comment: Not really. But when I contacted Salesforce support and showed them the issue I had, there was suddenly no issue extracting out the field. I was puzzled.